# remote javascript debug web application galaxy tab

Tags: android, debugging

I'am trying to debug a web application using this tutorial: https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/remote-debugging

When I go to chrome://inspect I can't found my device in the list

Can you help me please

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have Andorid SDK in your Desktop